# Как в simple html dom модифицировать страницу

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

К примеру добавить в head какой то скрипт или стиль, или изменить содержимое span в приведенном ниже коде?

```
<head></head><body><span>text</span></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Практически из прилагающихся [примеров](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
$html = str_get_html('<head></head><body><span>text</span></body>');    
$html->find('head', 0)->innertext = '<script>alert("Test");</script>';
$html->find('span', 0)->innertext = 'New text';
```

Добавление скрипта тоже не сложно реализуется:

```
$html->find('head', 0)->innertext .= '<script>alert("Test");</script>';
```

PS. Обратите внимание на точку

Comment: А как скрипт именно добавить в head? а не заменить полностью на своё содержимое

Comment: @SdafsFasafs обновил ответ